# Segurança aplicação Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, front-end, back-end

Tenho dúvidas sobre segurança, vou exemplificar :

No meu *front*, na minha `controller` tenho esse método:

```
  $scope.getAllpessoaGrid = function (strPesquisa, tipopessoa) {
    $scope.progressbar.start();
    $http.post("/pessoa/getAll", { strPesquisa: strPesquisa, tipopessoa: tipopessoa })
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.gridOptions.data = data;

        })
        .error(function (error) {

            $scope.progressbar.complete();
        });
};
```

Após executar, é retornado um **JSON**, que fica **exposto** no debug do browser, qualquer um pode ver os dados retornados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como esconder esse retorno do *backend*?

Comment: Jovem, alguma das respostas solucionou seu problema? Se sim, marque-a como correta, caso contrário, deixe um comentário para sabermos o que pode ser melhorado.

Answer (score 8):

Naturalmente é impossível. Tudo que roda no *browser* pode ser acessado (até modificado) pelo usuário.

Uma alternativa simples, se for o caso, é criptografar a **`string`** que é retornada pelo *server-side*. Isso aumenta um pouco a complexidade da aplicação porque sempre vai ser necessário descriptografar os dados que forem transmitidos do cliente pro servidor e vice-versa.

De qualquer forma se o usuário for um pouco "esperto" vai conseguir ver os dados, porque em algum momento isso vai precisar ser descriptografado para ser usado no *client-side*.

Aliás, se o usuário já vai conseguir ver estas informações pela *interface* faz sentido escondê-las dele?

Exemplo de um *payload* legível

```
{ "usuario": {"nome": "Jéferson"} }
```

E em Base64

```
"eyAidXN1YXJpbyI6IHsibm9tZSI6ICJKw6lmZXJzb24ifSB9"
```

Comment: Concordo! Não adianta tapar o sol com a peneira. Se o problema é retornar mais do que deveria, a solução é fazer o backend retornar apenas aquilo que só possa ser visto. Não há camuflagem que possa inibir um usuário mal intecionado.

Answer (score 8):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, parece que você está exibindo via interface algumas informações para o cliente, porém o JSON retornado está mostrando mais do que deveria!

Eu trabalho com Angular em sistemas que possuem acesso público e ao mesmo tempo, internamente, com controle de acesso.

O que eu faço para evitar qualquer tipo de problema de exposição é retornar exatamente aquilo que o usuário pode ver em cada situação.

Tomando um exemplo didático, utilizando o framework Laravel, eu crio rotas que retornam uma coisa para o usuário final que tem acesso público, outra coisa para o cliente, e ainda outra coisa para o administrador.

Exemplo:

```
  // Só o admin acessa, ele poderá ver tudo
  Route::get('/usuarios/ajax-listar-controle-acesso', function () {
      return Usuario::all();
  });

  // Clientes autenticados acessam, ele pode ver alguns dados
  Route::get('/usuarios/ajax-consulta', function () {
      return Usuario::select('id', 'telefone', 'nome', 'email')->get();
  });

  // Acesso público, informações limitadas para evitar exposições indevidas
  Route::get('/usuarios/ajax-consulta-web', function() {
      return Usuario::select('id', 'nome')->get();
  });
```

No final de contas a preocupação não é os dados ficarem expostos no navegador, mas sim como e pra quem expôr.

Se você quer controlar o que pode ser retornado para o navegador, faça a lógica no Backend para isso.

A segurança nesse caso não  é contar com a sorte que o  usuário final não veja um dado sensível porque ele não sabe acessar a ferramenta do desenvolvedor, mas sim você se precaver de exibir os dados conforme a necessidade e autorização.