# Proteger contra alterações no HTML, sem bloquear o console do navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, aplicação-web

Bom dia, como faço para impedir que o usuário inspecione o elemento html e modifique ele?
Pode exemplo:

Retorno um valor para tela e alimento ele dentro de um input chamado itemSaldo, ai o usuário poderá utilizar o campo quantidade para inserir uma quantidade que ele queira requisitar que tem que ser <= ao campo itemSaldo.

Sei que posso tratar isso diretamente no banco, mas existe alguma forma de tratar isso em tela?

Sem que eu tenha que bloquear o console do navegador.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como bloquear o console do navegador usando javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6035/como-bloquear-o-console-do-navegador-usando-javascript)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Segurança aplicação Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195626/seguran%c3%a7a-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não faz. **Tudo** que rodar no *browser* vai poder ser alterado pelo usuário.

Os tratamentos no *client-side* servem para melhorar a usabilidade da aplicação, você nunca pode confiar plenamente neles, sempre faça as validações no *server-side*.

Comment: Entendi, então não existe nenhum local que eu possa "guardar" o retorno do server-side e que não seja acessado pelo usuário?

Comment: Não existe. Você pode criptografar ou fazer algum esquema pra dificultar, mas aí já é outra questão. O que vem do servidor pode ser alterado pelo cliente **sempre**.